# What is the time zone for Google's Status Dashboards?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

Google has various dashboards like [G Suite Status Dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status), in which they mention dates and times.

But is there any way to know which time zone they refer to?

For example, here's the current output of [Gmail's specific dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=a45de3b26d6c5872f4cfe8e3424d7a82):

[image: Which time zone?]

10:21 AM in which time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention:

Further down the page it reads

**`All times are shown in your local timezone unless otherwise noted.`**

[image]